# Call a private $var via a static method in php without instanciating any object

Tags: php, oop

I m still beginner in php and was wondering something :
I learnd that a public static method could be called without instanciating the class like that :

```
Myclass::MyStaticFunction();
```

In the following example, I tried to do so, but it returns an error :

```
class Test {
    private $var;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->var = 5;
    }

    public static function getVar(){
        return $this->var;
    }
}

echo Test::getVar();
```

The error looks like this :

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

What would I use instead of `$this->` ?

Comment: use self instead of $this

Comment: @Mehedi-PSTU: `self` is fine, but `$var` would also have to be made static, and it would have to assign a value in the declaration, as the constructor will not run for the static call.

Comment: Why isn't the constructor running static call ? (sorry, I really need to understant this mechanism).

Does this mean I'm obliged to set the variable outside the constructor ?